# Remove-MsolGroupMember use exchange online to perform this operation

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I get the error:

> Remove-MsoLGroupMember : You cannot update mail-enabled groups using
>   this cmdlet. Use Exchange Online to perform this operation

But i have connected to a remote session and imported the exchange online module, why does it still throw error?

```
$credential = Get-Credential
$lyncSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential
$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $credential -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
Get-PSSession
Import-PSSession $exchangeSession

Remove-MsoLGroupMember -GroupObjectId $Group_GUID -GroupMemberType User -GroupmemberObjectId $GroupMembers.ObjectId
```

I was following this link to setup my remote connection to exchange, but i must be doing something wrong. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn362787(v=ocs.15).aspx

Comment: Remove-MSOLGroupMember isn't an Exchange Online command, this is why you get the error. You can try using Remove-DistributiongroupMember (not 100% sure if that is the specific EXO cmdlet, I have no machine to verify it on at the moment)

Comment: Remove-DistributiongroupMember does not seem to be working either. I get the error, "The current operation is not supported on GroupMailbox." as i described in a comment on A Seyam's answer.

Comment: then it must be a unifiedgroup which uses Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks as the command to remove groupmembers. Note that this is clearly documented by Microsoft, any person who manages O365 (especially with Powershell) should know the differences between the group types and how to manage them.

Comment: Thank you bluuf! I just came across that resource! One additional question on this however, how would i remove a user not knowing if they are an owner or member? Becaue with remove-unifiedgrouplins you must supply -LinkType of either member, owner, or subscriber. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use Remove-DistributionGroupMember instead if you are working with mail enabled security group as Remove-MsoLGroupMember works with regular security groups.
check this: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998016(v=exchg.160).aspx

Comment: Couple things on this, 1) I can not pass the GUID to the identity parameter, I get an error (even though that link says you can pass it) 2) when i try to use a different paramenter to identify the group (like the groups email) i get this error, "The current operation is not supported on GroupMailbox."

Comment: Please share the script you are using after removing private info